# "I want to apologize personally for..." or "I want to personally apologize for..."

Tags: adverb-position

The latter seems to have a more standard structure, but the first one sounds better to me. Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["It really doesn't matter" v "It doesn't really matter"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/414675/it-really-doesnt-matter-v-it-doesnt-really-matter)

Answer (score 1):

Although you're right, both are grammatically correct, the context of the words matter a lot. "Apologize personally for...", sounds like the apology is not going to be what is personal, but the action or person you are apologizing for is a personal issue to you or your character.

When you say you want to "personally apologize", you are putting yourself in this moment and want to make sure that this apology is coming from you. It carries a deep message, one being that this is information that needs to be said by me, or it would be a detriment to myself.  Well, maybe not that deep but you get it.